# FFmpeg does not see setted frontend0 parameters

Tags: c, ffmpeg, centos

I am setted DVB parameters like this :

```
static struct dtv_property props[] = {
{ .cmd = DTV_DELIVERY_SYSTEM, .u.data = SYS_DVBT2 },
{ .cmd = DTV_FREQUENCY,       .u.data = 474000000 },
{ .cmd = DTV_MODULATION,      .u.data = QAM_64 },
{ .cmd = DTV_INVERSION,       .u.data = INVERSION_AUTO },
{ .cmd = DTV_INNER_FEC,       .u.data = FEC_AUTO },
{ .cmd = DTV_TUNE ,           .u.data = FE_SET_FRONTEND},
{ .cmd = DTV_BANDWIDTH_HZ ,   .u.data = 8 },
};

static struct dtv_properties dtv_prop = {
.num = 7, .props = props
};
```

So then I am trying to use this setted DVB use in FFmpeg but it gets error.Why FFmpeg doesn't see Frontend0?

```
if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0", NULL, NULL)!=0)
{
    printf("error");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've got dvb-apps installed? You need to create a channel config file before you can grab a stream. zap the frontend and then use ffmpeg.

Comment: I have used w_scan and tzap.after i ran this command avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0", NULL, NULL) but it gets error

Comment: in ffmpeg /dev/dvb/adapter0/dvr0: Device or resource busy

Comment: I don't know if this actually works, but take a look at the bottom answer here: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1516

Comment: i have done it like in above instruction but when i run ffmpeg -i /dev/dvb/adapter0/dvr0 it loops and shows nothing

Comment: Yeah, I've never used it like you are. I've used dvblast to broadcast channels over UDP from dvb-t and dvb-s. w_scan to create a channel config file, zap for signal testing and dvblast for iptv broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

your source is wrong and incomplete; you filled in an array of struct dtv_property, but it is nowhere send to the frontend at all via ioctl.

Step1: An ioctl() something like this is missing (fd is int as returned by previous call to open() on the frontend device) to do the actual tuning:

```
    if ((ioctl(fd, FE_SET_PROPERTY, &dtv_prop)) != 0) {
        perror("FE_SET_PROPERTY failed");
        // do something on error here..
        }
```

And fix your array values, bandwidth needs to be set *before* DTV_TUNE, DTV_TUNE has no arg at all and is last item in sequence. Also: DTV_BANDWIDTH_HZ is in Hz, not MHz.

Step2: while the frontend is still kept open(!), open the demux device, either ie. "/dev/dvb/adapter0/demux0" or "/dev/dvb/adapter0/dvr0" and set the PID filters on that device. Before choosing either device, read the doc about the difference.

Step3: dont try to read from a dvb frontend. Read from demux while the frontend is still opened. The frontend is only used to receive tune commands or reply signal stats, but MPEG TS data is received from demux. As soon as frontend is closed, you cannot read anything from demux anymore, so keep it open. Therefore
3.1 open demux
3.2 use DMX_SET_FILTER ioctl or DMX_SET_PES_FILTER ioctl to define the data (PIDs) you want to receive.
3.3 read from demux device and send to ffmpeg

All of this well documented, may be you should just read the docs.